# Import { ref,computed} from 'vue' not working in nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm very new in nuxt and vuejs so this might be a dumb question.
I'm trying to import ref and computed to my Sidebar component but I'm getting a warning.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQid2.png)

What can I do to fix that ?
this is how I tried to do it

```
import {ref,computed} from 'vue';
```

Comment: Try this:
import {ref,computed} from '@nuxtjs/composition-api`

Comment: @ArezouSaremian I just tried your method.I had to install the @nuxtjs/composition-api then after I changed the import I got a bunch of these errors when compiling      ERROR  Failed to compile with 71 errors                                                               friendly-errors 12:09:40


 ERROR  in ./node_modules/@nuxtjs/composition-api/dist/runtime/index.mjs                               friendly-errors 12:09:40

Can't import the named export 'computed' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Comment: Afaik, it should already be available without an import.